# Transferring from "Populate" CMS to WordPress

Tags: installation, migration

Okay, apologies up front for being such a coding novice. I am transferring a web site (not a blog) from a CMS called Populate over to WordPress, from one hosting to a different hosting. I don't have access to the source files on the current host. (Long story short, I'm not a code/site thief: the owner of the site business and its domain is locked out by her former admin. She asked me to help her transfer her site.) So... I'm looking at a lot of copying and pasting -- field by field! -- of the content from Populate over to WordPress.
QUESTION: Is there a more efficient way to do this? I can grab source code from View Source, of course, but what good is that for plugging wholesale into Word Press? And I don't write PHP (shame on me, eh?) Or is there a way to do that? (Fingers crossed!)
Thanks a ton!
C

Comment: Does Populate have any export options at all? Your problem is essentially not getting content into WordPress, but getting it out of Populate.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress exports and imports its own posts through WordPress eXtended RSS (WXR). If you have access to an RSS feed of you content that's a good start. If you have access to templates powering your site then look at extending basic RSS with WXR fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the [WordPress Import HTML plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/). You can read more about it on the [authors blog](http://sillybean.net/code/wordpress/html-import/).

You would have to visit each page in your browser and do a save as html then upload all files according to the plugin instructions to your new server before you run the import.

I attended a presentation of the plugin the author gave at a WordCamp and it works great.

Comment: This seems like the way to go if you are really locked out. You could also use a copy such as this one: http://www.httrack.com/ to prevent you having to save each page individually.